# jquery fadeIn/fadeOut ie cleartype glitch

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, fadein, fadeout, cleartype

I´m currently trying to add the feature that is discussed here: http://blog.bmn.name/2008/03/jquery-fadeinfadeout-ie-cleartype-glitch/

A glitch in IE7 when fading with the .fadeIn() and .fadeOut() in jQuery, IE drops the windows Cleartype rendering; which results in very ugly text.

Am I understanding it correctly if I say that I could replace:

```
.fadeIn()
```

with

```
.customFadeIn('slow', function(customFades) {})
```

?
assuming I have function customFades()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some fix'n and trix'n... works now :)

```
    function customFades() {
    (function($) {
        $.fn.fadeIn = function(speed, callback) {
            return this.animate({opacity: 'show'}, speed, function() {
                if (jQuery.browser.msie) 
                    this.style.removeAttribute('filter'); 
                if (jQuery.isFunction(callback))
                    callback(); 
            });
        };

        $.fn.fadeOut = function(speed, callback) {
            return this.animate({opacity: 'hide'}, speed, function() {
                if (jQuery.browser.msie) 
                    this.style.removeAttribute('filter'); 
                if (jQuery.isFunction(callback))
                    callback(); 
            });
        };
    })(jQuery);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace it with

```
.customFadeIn('slow')
```

In your example. The second parameter is still an optional callback. If you don't need the callback, you can just use the single-parameter version.

If you have a callback to use:

```
.customFadeIn('slow', myCallback) // assumes function myCallback() exists
```

The point of this customFadeIn stuff is just to keep you from having to remove the filter every time you use a fade.

Comment: Hmm.. I cant find the problem.. the callback is running and working but I still get the ie glitch :/

Comment: Just to be sure, did you add in the actual implementation of "customFadeIn" detailed in that blog post?

Comment: Yes it´s there and running.. still not getting it to work and also it breaking my ajaxloader div :P

Comment: I just keep getting "$ajaxContainer.html(response).hide().customFadeIn is not a function"

Comment: This is the js "var $responseHTML = $(response).hide().appendTo(ajaxElement).fadeIn('slow', function(){});"

Answer (score 1):

http://www.kevinleary.net/jquery-fadein-fadeout-problems-in-internet-explorer/